# Why can we reverse a string by writing like this: str = str[::-1]?

Tags: python

Somebody told me you can reverse a string like this:

```
a='123456'
a = a[::-1]
print a
```

I just don't know how it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: This question is phrased in a way that'd make sense to someone who's not heard the term "slice notation", so I don't think it's an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

That takes advantage of Python's [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation).  Basically, it returns a new string created by stepping backwards through the original string.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> mystr = "abcde"    
>>> mystr[::-1]
'edcba'
>>> for i in mystr[::-1]:
...     print i
...
e
d
c
b
a
>>>
```

The format for slice notation is `[start:stop:step]`.

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter is the step size. Try some different step sizes to get the idea

```
>>> a = '123456'
>>> a[::2]
'135'
>>> a[::3]
'14'
>>> a[::-3]
'63'
>>> a[::-2]
'642'
>>> a[::-1]
'654321'
```

Since the start and stop are left empty, Python will choose them to step along the whole string.

Comment: think you,I gotta it!

Answer (score 2):

In Python negative slicing wraps around, so -1 is the last element.

```
[1,2,3,4][-1] = 4
```

In slice notation the first two elements are the bounds and the third is the index increment. By default the increment is 1.

```
[1,2,3,4,5][1:4] == [2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4,5][1:4:2] == [2,4]
```

Python also lets omit the bound indices to refer to the whole list `[::]`.

```
[1,2,3,4,5][::1] == [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So if your increment is negative you reverse the list by indexing backwards from the end.

```
[1,2,3,4,5][::-1] == [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Strings implement the same iterable protocol as lists so instead of reversing elements in a list you are reversing characters in a string.